# Custom Error Handler for retrofit failure cases

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm new to retrofit, and attempting to set a converter that will automatically deserialize error messages for `result.errorBody`

**CustomErrorHandler**

```
class CustomErrorHandler(private val gson: Gson) : Converter<ResponseBody, Error> {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun convert(responseBody: ResponseBody): Error {
        val error = gson.fromJson(responseBody.charStream(), Error::class.java)
        responseBody.close()
        throw Exception(error.message)
    }

    class Factory(private val gson: Gson) : Converter.Factory() {

        override fun responseBodyConverter(type: Type, annotations: Array<Annotation>, retrofit: Retrofit): Converter<ResponseBody, *>? {
            val typeToken = TypeToken.get(type)
            if (typeToken.rawType != Error::class.java) {
                return null
            }
            return CustomErrorHandler(gson)
        }

    }
}
```

---

**Retrofit**

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://192.168.0.1:8080")
    .addConverterFactory(CustomErrorHandler.Factory(GsonBuilder().create()))
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
```

---

**Error**

```
data class Error(val code: String, val message: String) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "code: $code, message: $message"
    }
}
```

---

**RoleService**

```
interface RoleService {
    @GET("/roles")
    @Headers("Accept: application/json")
    suspend fun findAll(): Response<List<Role>>
}
```

**Attempt #1**

expecting that following throw statement will have `result.errorBody` as the Error class or please advise on how it's supposed to be done.

```
suspend fun findAll(): List<Role>? {
    val result = roleService.findAll()
    if (result.isSuccessful)
        return result.body()
    throw Exception(result.errorBody().toString()) // result.errorBody to be Error class???
}
```

---

**Attempt #2**

A simple approach without using any converter and deserializing `errorBody` to `Error` class

```
suspend fun findAll(): List<Role>? {
    val result = roleService.findAll()
    if (result.isSuccessful)
        return result.body()
    val e = Gson().fromJson(result.errorBody().toString(), Error::class.java) // fails too
    throw Exception(e.message)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This inline solution helped, I couldn't get Converter working.

```
throw Exception(gson.fromJson(result.errorBody()?.string(), Error::class.java)?.message)
```

This code will help you.

```
suspend fun findAll(): List<Role>? {
    val result = roleService.findAll()
    if (result.isSuccessful)
        return result.body()
    throw Exception(gson.fromJson(result.errorBody()?.string(), Error::class.java)?.message)
}
```